# Partition Switching or Append Partition equivalent in Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there such feature in Big Query? this prevent any downtime on the table being updated and minimize resource utilization.

An alternative is view switching of which requires a the table being manipulated to be copied each time as described in https://cloud.google.com/solutions/bigquery-data-warehouse

Here's some documentation of the feature needed

https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2015/04/19/table-partitioning-in-sql-server-partition-switching/

Similar feature in AWS redshift but requires a delete command in target table first.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE_APPEND.html

Comment: Why would this feature be useful? Have you experienced any "downtimes"?

Comment: This feature is to prevent data integrity issues where users need to query multiple tables in  a single query. Currently our batch process takes about 2-3 hours updating the tables 1 by 1, hence in that window there's potential data issues.

Comment: Would views help with this? (Have analysts query tables through views. Stage all changes in separate tables, update all views to point to the new tables when done)

Comment: yep that's the old fashion an alternative ways already mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/solutions/bigquery-data-warehouse but it has a few disadvantages.

Comment: 1. If we create a copy of the table each time as suggested. it would prevent long term storage pricing and add extra time to copy the table.  2. if we maintain 2 full copy it and just update the partitions required it require double the storage

Comment: Since Google BigQuery definition is as a "fully managed, petabyte scale, low cost analytics data warehouse", the point is to query incredible huge amounts of data in a small time. It makes sense, then, to use views as Felippe pointed. For mission-critical relational database service with absolute transactional consistency at global scale, schemas, SQL, and automatic, synchronous replication for high availability then we would be talking about Cloud Spanner which is a different product. If you want to emulate it in BigQuery, then you will face this extra storage (and the related extra cost).

Answer (score 0):

Partition Exchange is possible in BigQuery now.
It has just a small perquisite that both the source and target table schema must be the same.

**Step 1: Identify which partition to be copied**

```
SELECT
 partition_id
FROM
  `dataset_id.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS` 
  where TABLE_NAME="table_name"
```

**Step 2: Copy the partition**

```
bq cp -f 'project:dataset_id.source_table$partition_id' 'project:dataset_id.target_table$partition_id'
```

> -f is for Overwrite
>
> -a is for Append

The same thing can be done using the API as well.